# How to create a DateTime from a DateTimeInterface in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

This is a rather simple question, but I couldn't really find an answer on the Internet.

So suppose, in PHP, I have an instance of a `DateTimeInterface`, and I need a `DateTime` for the same moment in time. What is the preferred way to do so? Conversion via a string seems rather convoluted, and I'm not sure which format to use. Maybe via the timestamp? I'm not sure if this will work when timezones are involved.

Comment: With the [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword, just like any other object. Note that date times are more than just a moment time; they also have location information, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP 8: [createFromInterface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfrominterface.php):

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromInterface($dateTimeInterface);
```

Answer (score 2):

In you are in PHP 7 (and maybe even earlier), this little helper class can do the trick for you:

```
class DateTimeConverter
{
    public static function mutableFromInterface(\DateTimeInterface $dateTimeInterface): \DateTime
    {
        return new \DateTime('@'.$dateTimeInterface->getTimestamp(), $dateTimeInterface->getTimezone());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth to mention, that time zone is ignored when you pass a timestamp to the constructor. See [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#104111). 
It should be composed by setters instead: 
```php
$result = new \DateTime();
$result->setTimestamp($dateTimeInterface->getTimestamp());
$result->setTimezone($dateTimeInterface->getTimezone());
```